# WPF Windows Open File Dialog taking too long to open

Tags: wpf

Sorry to bother you with such question that seams more like one of those question you should make to a Windows technical support, but I have no one else to turn to so here it goes.
VS2013 upgraded from VS2012, using c# .NET 4.5 with WPF.
From time to time, I can notice that my open directory dialog box takes ages to appear.
Here you can see some code:

```
// Configure open file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = MultiSimControls.Resources.message_resource.Resource_xml_extension; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = MultiSimControls.Resources.message_resource.Message_open_file_dialog_xml_filter;  // Filter files by extension 

// Shows open file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result != true) return;

// Process open file dialog box results 
string XMLFileName = dlg.FileName;
...
```

My Machine:
    OS Name Microsoft Windows 8.1
    Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600
    Other OS Description    Not Available
    OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
    System Name PC00933
    System Manufacturer Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    System Model    GE60 2OC\2OE
    System Type x64-based PC
    System SKU  To be filled by O.E.M.
    Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
    BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. E16GCIMS.509, 4/24/2013
    SMBIOS Version  2.7
    Embedded Controller Version 255.255
    BIOS Mode   UEFI
    BaseBoard Manufacturer  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    BaseBoard Model Not Available
    BaseBoard Name  Base Board
    Platform Role   Mobile
    Secure Boot State   On
    PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
    Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
    System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
    Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume3
    Locale  United States
    Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.3.9600.17196"
    Anti virus: Symantec Endpoint Protection ver. 12.1.4013.4013

My question: 
Has anyone else experienced this issue too? If yes, would you please provide information on how you did to solve it?

Thanks in advance for your time and any thoughts you may judge helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` remembers the last folder used, even if you restart the process.

My assumption is, that the remembered folder isn't accessible (i.e. disconnected network share) which causes that delay. You can set an initial directory to an always accessible folder before opening the dialog.

```
dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; // or better use a SpecialFolder like MyDocuments
```

Comment: The folder is in fact accessible.
But now that you say, I have some shares available on my favorites and I've also noticed the slowing problem with other applications like notepad++ and the Windows Notepad application. Windows Notepad actually shows that my Desktop is not accessible!!!!
After removing the shared folder from my Favorite folders list, everything is OK now.
Thanks a lot DanielB!!!